# As3 imported custom class won't access components at main stage

Tags: actionscript-3, components

I have this situation. I was building all in code, but it's a little painful, so I made a interface with components using the Flash drawing capabilities.

I got a main class, as usual, with the interface in a MovieClip instance called "AreaEdit". In my custom class "EditorHTML" there is a Sprite:

```
private var dTela:Sprite;
```

So the constructor is like this:

```
public function EditorHTML(instEdit) {
    this.Parags = new Array();
    this.dTela = instEdit;
    trace("dTela: "+this.dTela.width+" x "+this.dTela.height);
}
```

At the main class:

```
Escrit = new EditorHTML(AreaEdit);
```

So trace displays the dimensions of the box, as expected. However, at the custom class, if I try to access an instance inside like this:

```
this.dTela.cxEdit.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, atualizar);
```

An error is returned: /Library/WebServer/Documents/as3/bibliotecas_externas/com/gustavopi/txt/EditorHTML.as, Line 49    1119: Access of possibly undefined property cxEdit through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite.

I did a test and the same instance "cxEdit" is available in main class. So it seams the components instances are not available for a custom class. How do I solve this?

Comment: Error says that `AreaEdit` is `Sprite` , not `MovieClip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call it like this:

```
  Sprite( Sprite(this.dTela).getChildByName("cxEdit")).addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, atualizar);
```

In case that `cxEdit` is a `Sprite` too.

**Edited**: cxEdit must be a `TextArea`. So it can be done like this:

```
var cxEdit:TextArea = TextArea(Sprite(this.dTela).getChildByName("cxEdit"));
cxEdit.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, atualizar);
```

To make it easier for the rest of the code...

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are trying to access the "cxEdit" as a property of Sprite (dTela), which is not a Sprite property, hence the error.

Could you perhaps pass in AreaEdit.cxEdit as the argument instead of just AreaEdit?

Comment: Is useless because there is a lot of other components inside AreaEdit. The solution must cover all.

Comment: Perhaps you could create references to each component in the Custom class.